# Laravel redirect intended with inputs after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

1. Let's say a user has already logged in and filling a random form on my system.
2. Upon submit, if the session is not present, system redirects to login page.
3. I am trying to develop something returns to the last active form after login `->withInput()` parameters.

**FormController.php:**

```
public function saveForm(){
   if(Auth::check()){
      //get inputs and submit form
   }else{
      //redirect to login page
      return Redirect::route(login);
   }
}
```

**LoginController.php**

```
if(Auth::attempt($loginData)){
   //redirect to the last active form before login, with inputs before login
   return Redirect::intended('pageName')->withInput();
}
```

Comment: This situation is so rare I would not waste time on it, instead, I would refresh session using AJAX, when user is typing anything.

Comment: I think that a new Session is Created, When the User is logged in, so your old saved Data is not avaible in that session. You would have to save the values in a cookie or in the database. So it's quite a load of work.

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to know if there's an easier way to do that. I'll be using ajax. Thanks.

Comment: Would be great if you can mark my answer as the correct answer. :)

Comment: Sure, thank you for your participation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new session is created when logging in a new user in Laravel. Old session data like the form input is then flashed so you are not able to access these anymore.

Saving the input data in the database or in a cookie would work, but is a lot of work for that rare situation.